Open a browser from firebase push-notification without launching the application?
I want a simple feature, when application is in killed state I want it to open a browser instead of application when user clicks on the notification.
public void showNotification(Context context) {
    // Define the URL to open
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com");

    // Create an intent to open the browser
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Ensure the browser is opened, not your app
    intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome"); // Optional: Specify Chrome (or remove for default browser)

    // Create the PendingIntent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    );

    // Build the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Open Browser")
            .setContentText("Click to view the website.")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // Display the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}


Right now the application gets open first.
